# Tkinter Bind method to Space Key

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't find why I cannot bind my space key to the method trial. trial is not called when I press the space key.

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk

class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):    
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)             
        self.can = tk.Canvas( self,height=100, width=100) 
        self.can.pack()
        self.focus_set() 

        self.can.bind('<space>', self.trial) 

    def trial(self, event):
        print("Fire")


#------ Main ------------------------------------------------------------------    
launch = Game()
launch.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `.bind('<KeyPress-space>'`

Comment: .bind('<KeyPress-space>' does not change unfortunately

Comment: @stovfl: nope, that's not the problem. `<space>` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the focus on the root window instead of the canvas. You need to set the focus on the canvas since it doesn't get focus by default.

```
self.can.focus_set()
```